# Angular UI Bootstrap accordion disappears after open/close panel on Chrome 51 for Mac

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to place a google maps directions panel inside an angular-ui-bootstrap accordion. Unfortunately, when I open and close the panel that contains the google directions, the panel disappears. 
See screenshot here: [Accordion disappears after closing the accordion panel. The only thing that still shows up are the chevron icons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbTxA.png)

The weird thing is that the panel reappears again if I resize the browser window. I've been trying to debug this issue and noticed this issue happens on Chrome 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit) for Mac, but not on Safari 9.1.1.

I was able to replicate the issue in this plunker ( https://plnkr.co/edit/FpxAbxSBPB4XBRejA1Fe?p=preview ) by copy/pasting the google directions panel 'div' element inside the accordion, and opening and closing the accordion panel.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue? If you're not able to replicate the issue with the plunker, do you have any suggestions on how should I place google maps directions inside an angular-ui-bootstrap accordion? Thanks!!!

The code:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true">
  <uib-accordion-group is-open="isOption2Open" ui-sref="option2" template-url="accordion-group.html">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      Option2 <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isOption2Open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isOption2Open}"></i>
    </uib-accordion-heading>

    <div class="center">
      <button type="button" id="calc_route" ng-click="calcMillRoute();" disabled>Calculate Route</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="clearMap()">Clear</button>
    </div>

    <div id="directions-panel">
      <hr>
      <div id="panel-header" class="center">
          <span>Directions </span>
          <button type="button" class="action-button" id="reverse" ng-click='reverseDirections()'>Reverse</button>
      </div>
      <div id='panel-body'>
       <!-- Google Maps Directions Panel goes here  -->
      </div>
  </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Comment: thr is no wrong in the plunker if i open and close still accordion is ther

Comment: hmm.. @gayathri: Thanks for letting me know. Are you also using Chrome for Mac?

Comment: i am using windows chrome

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with Chrome for Mac.

Similar to the issue described [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=390604) on Comment #14, I noticed this issue only happens when I float the side panel (div that encloses the accordion). I was able to solve my problem by adding "position: relative" to the #side_panel css (workaround proposed in Comment #17).